# Different syntax for #define in C/C++ including many statements

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I understand the syntax of `#define` like,

```
#define Pi 3.14
```

So it's obvious that we can use `Pi` constant instead of `3.14` anywhere in code to make code more readable.

But I encountered a syntax like below.

Does it mean whenever I call the macro

```
doIT("hello world");
```

the code statements within {...} will be invoked ?

Does `#define` allow to give such syntax.? 
What does the `__FUNCTION__`, `__VA_ARGS__` mean ?

```
#define doIT(str, ...)                                                                      \
{                                                                                               \
    if (pDoLog) pDoLog->LogMsg("[%s] Error: " str, LOG_WRONG, __FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    printf("[%s] Error: " str "\n", __FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__);                               \
}
```

Comment: you might want to read up on [preprocessor macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace), specifically function-like macros.

Comment: It's good practice to wrap statement block in a `do { ...} while(false)` ala `#define doIT(str, ...) do { if ...; printf ...; } while (false)` - that way if you write code like `if (whatever) doIT("%d", i); else ...;` the macro substitution won't give you `if (...) { }; else ...;` - note the semicolon after the `}` and before the `else` - that causes a compilation error because there's no "open" `if` statement for the `else` to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "call" a macro, and its expansion doesn't get "invoked". The preprocessor just replaces the macro with its expansion, before the code gets compiled.

A macro defined with parentheses such as `doIt(str)` is a "function-like macro" which means it takes arguments which can be used in the expansion of the macro.

A function-like macro with `...` in the argument list indicates it can accept a variable number of arguments. The special predefined symbol `__VA_ARGS__` expands to the list of arguments passed to the `...` placeholder.

`__FUNCTION__` is a special predefined symbol that expands to the name of the current function being compiled, so wherever the macro gets expanded it will use the name of the enclosing function.